# HTML -> Fixed top, Fixed bottom and dynamic content

Tags: html, css, layout

i would like to create a single page where:

1) The top, 100px, fixed
2) The bottom, 100px, fixed
3) Between top and bottom there is dynamic content

I was able to create exactly that but i have an issue, when i am scrolling the dynamic content, the elements go under and over the top and bottom and the same elements are visible thru the fixed top/bottom.

I tried clear: both; on the top and bottom div, but since they are fixed, the clear: both; did'nt works.

I would like to keep the dynamics elements inside the content div between top and bottom and if possible still use the main document scroll bar to scroll inside it.

Here is an example, assume the lines represent the top and bottom fixed div, and the 'element' are the dynamic contents.

element - not correct

---

element - not correct

---

element

element

element

element

element

---

element - not correct

---

element - not correct

Hope i am clear enough and thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you create a jsfiddle to help us understand you better? jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess this is what you're looking for.

See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aniketpant/ttQAz/).

### HTML

```
<header>
    This is the header!
</header>
<article>
    <p>Goodness one unimaginative rooster some that circa much jay goodness gosh pessimistic scantly dark some modest gasped where unexplainable some before about that a hello firefly macaw ethereally indecisive panda lorikeet where a peskily jellyfish a since lied factiously in and that after but falteringly so worm flabbily yet hey gladly more versus much precarious because a the boisterous quiet fed one alas hawk flawlessly thanks some.</p>
    <p>Squirrel much krill regarding before contrary jeez outdid warthog immaturely articulately valiant hey suggestive thus far won darn wow scorpion portentously more hotly miraculous jeepers meagerly since excluding that however pinched yet whale adoringly floppy tenably wow and after via for unproductively as one prior the more on urchin rang much because some more approving near oh a as far lion some lucky far much frog far and beneath underlay far after nosy jaguar subconscious after this far input frequently distant the much positively gagged jeez unobtrusively far sank less before babbled far by when this the this sensible outside.</p>
    <p>That far qualitatively intrepid vulture a ferret disgraceful moaned therefore easy much and curt insincerely dachshund notwithstanding yikes and dragonfly and patted until much jeez close fumed divisive copiously wherever near near far perceptible shrewdly ground yikes opened as elaborate adversely spilled that creepy imaginative by in hello groundhog magnificently jeez hence crud versus desperately caterpillar checked one wicked far some yikes.</p>
    <p>And darn dependent that urchin upon much jeez ably sniffed a less in far darn far incorrect between inept caterpillar man-of-war manta hence ironically into more amenable negative sanctimoniously tortoise eagle far spoiled clapped tepid yikes irresistibly testy warthog hugged immense much immense alas thus paid therefore agitatedly about well following the hey aboard and that after and condescending seagull because alas slept hey this went dove far much far considering raccoon witless under ungraceful.</p>
    <p>Emptied much gosh circuitously inside along a far pointed fanatic hey bravely with far yikes capybara meadowlark sedulous some lion squid floated darn drolly underwrote loving spat maliciously coaxing unwilling goodness seagull elephant snickered balked sloth for kookaburra inside untactfully so the where much human then because pungently cracked heard overtook firm skeptically reverently much some jeez less and hey towards.</p>
</article>
<footer>
    This is the footer!
</footer>
```

### CSS

```
body {
    font-family: sans-serif;
}

header, footer {
    position: fixed;
    height: 100px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    background: #ff0450;
    color: #fff;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    line-height: 6em;
}

header {
    top: 0;
}

footer {
    bottom: 0;
}

article {
    margin: 100px 50px 0;
}

article p {
    margin: 20px 0;
}

article p:first-line {
    font-variant: small-caps;
}
```

### Update

```
body {
    font-family: sans-serif;
}

header, footer {
    position: fixed;
    height: 100px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    background: #ff0450;
    color: #fff;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    line-height: 6em;
}

header:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    height: 20px;
    background: #fff;
    z-index: 999;
    top: -20px;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
}

footer:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    height: 20px;
    background: #fff;
    z-index: 999;
    bottom: -20px;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
}

header {
    top: 0;
    margin-top: 20px;
}

footer {
    bottom: 0;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

article {
    margin: 120px 50px 0;
}

article p {
    margin: 20px 0;
}

article p:first-line {
    font-variant: small-caps;
}
```

Updated the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aniketpant/ttQAz/) too.

Comment: Hi and thanks for the reply, it is what i need, however will it work in old browsers?

Comment: @Armkreuz It should work, I am not using a very unique technique. Just putting the header and footer to a fixed position. Try it out.

Comment: as Armkreuz wrote: "actually the top and bottom are not totally on top and bottom of the page(they have a padding/margin" but there are no margins in this example.

Comment: @rmagnum2002 You can make those minor changes. It's not much. Add those margins, by changing the value of `top` and `bottom`.

Comment: sure, I added the margins and here is the result, scrolling the text displays it under the header and footer.. http://jsfiddle.net/PxabT/51/ , there is more then margins to take care off. ;)

Comment: @rmagnum2002 Made the change to the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aniketpant/ttQAz/). And I am using `:before` and `:after` for it.

Comment: :) great, had no idea about using "before" in css. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

here, take a look at this.

http://jsfiddle.net/PxabT/47/

**update**

http://jsfiddle.net/R4SV5/7/

Comment: or here is a solution closer to your example provided by you on Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/R4SV5/5/

Answer (score 0):

Give the top and bottom elements a background-color or background image.  Also it is probably a good idea to give top and bottom a z-index of 3 or higher.

Comment: Hi and thanks for the reply, actually the top and bottom are not totally on top and bottom of the page(they have a padding/margin) so even when giving them a background color/image, the problem is there when scrolling.

Comment: Margin will leave a gap, but padding is inside the box and there should be no gap.